# PHP Passing 2D Arrays to CVS

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I am very, very new to php and require assistance.

I have built a multipage form. Most of the inputs on this form can be dynamically created by the user.

Here is a working example of this on [codepen](http://codepen.io/theodore_steiner/pen/BLvoLK)

When the data from the multiDimensional array is passed to the csv sheet I would like to arrange it in the following way: `Array ( [0] => Position [1] => Unit [2] => Unit President )`,

That way, if the user adds two or three inputs dynamically, it will be easier to see each entry.

So far I've only been able to filter the array like this:

```
$unitLevelPosition = $_POST["unitLevelPosition"];
    $unitLevelPositionValues = "";
    foreach( $unitLevelPosition as $unitPositionValue)
    {
        $educationHistoryValues .= $unitPositionValue;
    }
```

The array variable is then added to the rest of the variables being printed to the cvs like this:

$csvdata = $firstName . ", " . $lastName . ", " . $educationHistoryValues;
Is what I'm after even possible? And if so, can someone help me get started?

Comment: Instead `foreach` you can use a simple `join` function, and there is built in `fcsvput` function in PHP. Check these functions on net.

Comment: Does the fcsvput replace the fwrite/fclose portion of the code?

Comment: `fopen` and `flclose` is needed. It just help you to create a proper csv row.

Comment: Here's where I'm getting confused with that: In most of the examples I've seen, the fcsvput is on it's own like here (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) and not integrated in a list with other elements, and I'm not sure how to bridge that gap.  Can you show an example (if you have time) using some of my code above?

Comment: Every row is one array, then put it into file. See my answer.

Comment: That makes sense.  One more question because the array may be, for example, the third item in csv (so firstName, last name, UnitArray) when it comes time to fit the array in line with the other inputs, would your example, if statement and all, be saved to a variable and then inserted like so: $firstName . "," . $lastName . "," . $array1 . ",". ?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your question. Just try this example. Add if / else condions if you want.

Comment: What I mean is, the example you gave is only posting the array.  It's opening the file, posting and then closing. But, for my purposes, there are other values being posted to the csv of which the array is only one, like this $csvdata = $firstName . ", " . $lastName . ", " . $UnitPresientArrays.  My question is if I need to keep my array variables in this same format but I am opening and closing the files everytime the array loop is run, won't that prevent all the entries from the entire form from being on one line of the csv

Comment: Just use it. And change `fopen('file.csv', 'w');` the `w` to `a` if you want to append. When there is an empty entry, `"",` will be in the line. You are the programmer, you know what file you are using, what format is needed, before you insert it in file, you can validate entries, and put only if all required fields are filled... etc...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should change the name-attribute of your form.

Use instead of unitLevelPosition[] something like unitLevelPosition[0][name_of_field]. And for every new input-fields increase the index by 1. E.g. unitLevelPosition[1][name_of_field].
Then you will have an array which should look like this:

```
[
   0 => [
      'position' => value_of_input,
      'unit_president' => value_of_input,
       ... and so on ...
   ],
   1 => [
      'position' => value_of_input,
      'unit_president' => value_of_input,
       ... and so on ...
   ]
]
```

The next thing you have to do. Use the PHP-function fputcsv (http://php.net/manual/de/function.fputcsv.php) to create a CSV-File.

On this side you find a very good example, which you can use to create your CSV-file.

In short:

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach( $unitLevelPosition as $fields)
{
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: When you talk about changing the names do you mean when I am collecting the variable or back in the original html code?

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner I mean the name-attribute in your html-codes. e.g.: <input type="text" name="unitLevelPosition[0][position]" value=""/> and in your javascript-part, you just have to increase the index. e.g.: <input type="text" name="unitLevelPosition[1][position]" value=""/> and so on

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I'll give everything a go!

Answer (score -1):

What you need is something like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['position'])) {
    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($_POST['position'] as $key => $position) {
        //Do validation here...
        $fields = [
            'position' => $position,
            'unit' => $_POST['unit'][$key],
            'president' => $_POST['president'][$key],
            'date' => $_POST['date'][$key],
        ];
        fputcsv($fp, $fields, ',');
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

But change the input names like this:

```
<input type="text" name="position[]" value="" >
<input type="text" name="unit[]" value="" >
<input type="text" value="president[]">
<input type="text" value="date[]">
```